# Increase Comment Control page size

Tags: 2013, social, paging, comments

I'm rendering a Comment control on one of my pages. However, it only displays 5 comments before you have to page to the next 5 comments. How do I increase this page size? There is no attribute or webpart property that I can see

```
<SharePointPortalControls:SocialCommentControl ID="CommentControl" runat="server" />
```

I have tried:

```
CommentControl.Attributes.Add("DisplayItems", "10");
```

AND

```
CommentControl.Attributes["DisplayItems"] =  "10";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
PropertyInfo pi = typeof(SocialCommentControl).GetProperty("DisplayItems", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
pi.SetValue(CommentControl, 10);
```

Valid values for `DisplayItems` property are *1* through *10*. If you set it to less than *1* it will be considered as *1* and if you set it to more than *10* it will be considered as *10*.

Comment: Just saw this, I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You could directly access the backfield `m_displayItems` instead of using the property `DisplayItems`:

```
FieldInfo fi = typeof(SocialCommentControl).GetField("m_displayItems", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
fi.SetValue(CommentControl, 1000);
```

This way you can use a value greater than 10 (which is restricted in the property setter).